# opening an image in python using pyautogui module

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, pixel, pyautogui

I am trying to open an image using pyautogui so i can compare the images pixels. I have looked in the auto correction in visual studio code and I looked in a documentary about it. Can someone please tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well you can do it by PIL (pillow) like -

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open(r"path\to\image.png")

im.show()
```